# Microsoft Alias for Windows Account

Tags: windows, windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I have a hotmail.com account that I use for all my Windows devices. However, I've started transitioning all of my known online accounts to a new email. The reason for this is because my current email has my name in it and for privacy reasons, I am moving to a new email that does not have my name in it and is kind of a pun.

So, back to the post.

I created a Hotmail account with that name and tried to use that as an alias. However, I realized that you can't use a claimed email as an [alias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWSYT.png). So I thought, "No biggie! I'll just create a new account using the prompt." However, I soon realized that you can only create accounts using that option only as an @outlook.com [domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKmzp.png).

While it's not completely necessary that I do this, I was wondering if there's any chance I could get the @hotmail.com domain to work with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think, for email account itself, using @Outlook.com and using@Hotmail.com as Alias seems make no difference. If you only want to hide privacy information, creating new Outlook.com alias should be able help.

As I know, for hotmail and Outlook.com these kinds of personal email account, we could not get them work together via features like Exchange Send As. If necessary, you could use Outlook rules to redirect all the received emails to another email account.